# select() API used to sleep on mac returns immediately

Tags: macos, clang, sleep

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 500000L;
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

This sleeps for 5 seconds as expected on Linux but on MAC (Yosemite) it returns immediately?

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem in a test program — are you sure `select()` is actually returning immediately?

Comment: "used to sleep"? What? You mean the timeout?

Comment: What's the return value from `select()`? You may need to loop around it (recalculating the timeout) if it fails with `errno` being `EINTR`. Finally, I find no definitive statement about what `select()` does if `nfds` is 0 in its [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/select.2.html). From where are you getting the expectation that it sleeps for the timeout?